# Async flow in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

In my node.js application i want to make my flow synchronous. I faced this kind of issues previously, i solved it. But now i am struggling now in this situation.

```
for(var k=nearestMatchLength;k--;) {
    async.forEach(matchedArray[i].nearestmatch, function(elem,Callback){
       if(condition){
          app.models.Schedule.findById(elem.Id, function(err, res){
             for(){
             };----> for loop 
             Callback(); 
          });
       }
        Callback();
    });
}
```

In the above code `if(condition)` satisfied then the `findById(which is async)` is called and the  `Callback();` after that is called before its executes.

My flow should be if it entered into if condition the fetching should be done and then only the next loop should rotate.

Please share your ideas. thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `matchedArray[i].nearestmatch` an array?

Comment: @slebetman ys its an array..

Comment: Are you looking for `else` statement?

Comment: Outer `for` loop must be async too... `async.times` for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var k=nearestMatchLength;k--;) {
    async.forEach(matchedArray[i].nearestmatch, function(elem,Callback){
       if(condition){
          app.models.Schedule.findById(elem.Id, function(err, res){
             for(){
             };----> for loop 
             Callback(); 
          });
       }
       else{
        Callback();
       }
    });
}
```

the `else` is added there because your `app.models.Schedule.findById` has a callback `function(err, res)` which lets the bottom `Callback()` be called before even getting to the `function(err,res)` part.

so here is an example

```
console.log('A');
setTimeout(function(){
   console.log('B');
  },0);
console.log('C');
```

Whats the order of the letters printed here??

Its A, C then B

The example here is of `setTimeout` but it can be anyother function with a callback implemented.

Comment: Also, you can `return findById` instead of else.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `async.forEach`, and you can get rid of `for` loop

```
//async.times - execute fn number of times
async.times(nearestMatchLength, function(i, next){
    async.each(matchedArray[i].nearestmatch, function(elem, callback){
       if(true){
          app.models.Schedule.findById(elem.Id, function(err, result){
             //do something async
             //for example it's a new for loop
             async.each([1,2,3], function(number, cb) {
                //do some work
                result.number = number;
                //call cb to reach next iteration
                cb();
             }, function() {
                //all elements from [1,2,3] complete
                //do some async again and call next to complete
                //async.times execution
                result.save(next);
             });
          });
       } else {
          next(null);
       }
    });
}, function(err, done) {
    //complete
});
```